# Tab index is not working for dynamically added controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a web page where there is a requirement to repeat the controls in repeater. Tab indices are already assigned to the control. while repeating those controls by clicking plus button in repeater, they are taking same tab indices as corresponding to previous controls.

e.g. Tab index for CardHolderFirstName text box in first user control exactly matches with that of CardHolderFirstName text box in second user control. So when I press tab when focus is set to CardHolderFirstName text box in first user control, instead of setting focus to CardHolderMiddleName text box in first user control; it sets focus to CardHolderFirstName text box in second user control.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the tabstop property of your controls set to true?

Comment: Try to set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new control dynamically and want to control it with Tab, be sure to set the tabindex and tabstop property

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.TabIndex = 1;
button1.TabStop = true;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx)